# Set span width and height not only fill its content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set empty spans  with height and width by css but the span only fills its content

```
   <div class="container">
       <div id="widgets-container">
            <span class="widget" name="widget1" style="background-color: #CCFFFF;width:300px;height:200px"></span>
            <span class="widget" name="widget2" style="background-color: #FF8000;width:300px;height:200px"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

How can I set the span element to have the width and height?

PD:divs works but are block elements I need inline elements

Comment: Hi, the width and height of inline element  depends on its content. I think you need to set `display: inline-block;` in this situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add `span` to get `inline-block` property.

You Can achieve it with `display: inline-block`.

```css
.widget { 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div id="widgets-container">
           <div class="widget" name="widget1" style="background-color: #CCFFFF;width:300px;height:200px"></div>
           <div class="widget" name="widget2" style="background-color: #FF8000;width:300px;height:200px"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In added `display: inline-block` to your code. This sets default `width` for empty span as well as it does not change lines, here it is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="widgets-container">
        <span class="widget" name="widget1" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #CCFFFF;width:300px;height:200px"></span>
        <span class="widget" name="widget2" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #FF8000;width:300px;height:200px"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```